# Issue with sql query

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I've two tables `sermons(sermon_id,preacher_id,sermon_name etc)` and `preachers(preacher_id,firstname,lastname etc)`. Now i display this like 1st preacher name then all the sermons of that preacher and so on , this is working properly. But want to display preachers who have sermons...

following code is used but i got only the 1st preacher..

```
function viewAllpreachers($offset=0, $limit=null) {
        $preacher_ids = array();
        $this->db->distinct('preacher_id');
        $this->db->select('preacher_id');
        $this->db->from('sermons');

        $query = $this->db->get();

        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {

            foreach ($query->result() as $key => $res1) {

                $preacher = array();
                $this->db->select('*');
                $this->db->from('preacher');
                $this->db->where('preacher_id', $res1->preacher_id);
                $this->db->order_by('first_name');
                $query = $this->db->get('', $limit, $offset);
                if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {

                    foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
                        $preacher[$row->preacher_id]['preacher_id'] = $row->preacher_id;
                        $preacher[$row->preacher_id]['preacher_name'] = $row->first_name . ' ' . $row->last_name;
                        $preacher[$row->preacher_id]['preacher_image'] = $row->preacher_image;
                        $preacher[$row->preacher_id]['preacher_bio_brief'] = $row->preacher_bio_brief;

                        $this->db->select('*');
                        $this->db->from('sermons');
                        $this->db->where('preacher_id', $row->preacher_id);
                        $this->db->order_by('sort_order ');
                        $sermon_array = array();

                        $query = $this->db->get();
                        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
                            foreach ($query->result() as $row1) {
                                $sermon_array[$row1->sermon_id] ['sermon_image'] = $row1->sermon_image;
                                $sermon_array[$row1->sermon_id] ['sermon_title'] = $row1->sermon_title;
                                $sermon_array[$row1->sermon_id] ['audio_file'] = $row1->audio_file;
                                $sermon_array[$row1->sermon_id] ['sermon_description'] = $row1->sermon_description;
                            }
                        }
                        $preacher[$row->preacher_id]['sermon'] = $sermon_array;
                    }
                    return $preacher;
                }
            }  }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Would it not be a case of simple inner join ?

Comment: I want to display all preachers who have sermons. if a preacher have no semons, won't display his details

Comment: In your code, you have `return $preacher;` which will return and leave the function after the first `$preacher` have been looped over. Save all preachers in a separate array and then return the array of preachers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
use this code

 $preacher = array();
                $this->db->select('*');
                $this->db->from('preacher');
                $this->db->join('preacher','sermons.preacher_id=preacher.preacher_id');
                $this->db->order_by('first_name');
                $query = $this->db->get('', $limit, $offset);
                if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {

                    foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
                        $preacher[$row->preacher_id]['preacher_id'] = $row->preacher_id;
                        $preacher[$row->preacher_id]['preacher_name'] = $row->first_name . ' ' . $row->last_name;
                        $preacher[$row->preacher_id]['preacher_image'] = $row->preacher_image;
                        $preacher[$row->preacher_id]['preacher_bio_brief'] = $row->preacher_bio_brief;

                        $this->db->select('*');
                        $this->db->from('sermons');
                        $this->db->where('preacher_id', $row->preacher_id);
                        $this->db->order_by('sort_order ');
                        $sermon_array = array();

                        $query = $this->db->get();
                        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
                            foreach ($query->result() as $row1) {
                                $sermon_array[$row1->sermon_id] ['sermon_image'] = $row1->sermon_image;
                                $sermon_array[$row1->sermon_id] ['sermon_title'] = $row1->sermon_title;
                                $sermon_array[$row1->sermon_id] ['audio_file'] = $row1->audio_file;
                                $sermon_array[$row1->sermon_id] ['sermon_description'] = $row1->sermon_description;
                            }
                        }
                        $preacher[$row->preacher_id]['sermon'] = $sermon_array;
                    }
                    return $preacher;

            }
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display preacher with sermon you should add a JOIN to your query, this way if the preacher doesn't have a sermon it won't come up in the resulting rowset.

i.e.:

```
function viewAllpreachers($offset=0, $limit=null) {
        $preacher_ids = array();
        $this->db->distinct('preacher_id');
        $this->db->select('preacher_id');
        $this->db->from('sermons');

        $query = $this->db->get();

        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {

            foreach ($query->result() as $key => $res1) {

                $preacher = array();
                $this->db->select('*');
                $this->db->from('preacher');
                $this->db->join('sermons', 'preacher.preacher_id = sermons.preacher_id');
                $this->db->where('preacher_id', $res1->preacher_id);
                $this->db->order_by('first_name');
                $query = $this->db->get('', $limit, $offset);
                if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {

                    foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
                        $preacher[$row->preacher_id]['preacher_id'] = $row->preacher_id;
                        $preacher[$row->preacher_id]['preacher_name'] = $row->first_name . ' ' . $row->last_name;
                        $preacher[$row->preacher_id]['preacher_image'] = $row->preacher_image;
                        $preacher[$row->preacher_id]['preacher_bio_brief'] = $row->preacher_bio_brief;

                        $this->db->select('*');
                        $this->db->from('sermons');
                        $this->db->where('preacher_id', $row->preacher_id);
                        $this->db->order_by('sort_order ');
                        $sermon_array = array();

                        $query = $this->db->get();
                        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
                            foreach ($query->result() as $row1) {
                                $sermon_array[$row1->sermon_id] ['sermon_image'] = $row1->sermon_image;
                                $sermon_array[$row1->sermon_id] ['sermon_title'] = $row1->sermon_title;
                                $sermon_array[$row1->sermon_id] ['audio_file'] = $row1->audio_file;
                                $sermon_array[$row1->sermon_id] ['sermon_description'] = $row1->sermon_description;
                            }
                        }
                        $preacher[$row->preacher_id]['sermon'] = $sermon_array;
                    }
                    return $preacher;
                }
            }  }
        return false;
    }
```

Note: Is there a specific reason why you are using two queries and not only one, you should be able to retrieve the list of preachers having a sermon in one SQL query.

```
function viewAllpreachers($offset=0, $limit=null) {
    $preacher = array();
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('preacher');
    $this->db->join('sermons', 'preacher.preacher_id = sermons.preacher_id');
    $this->db->where('preacher_id', $res1->preacher_id);
    $this->db->order_by('first_name');

    $query = $this->db->get('', $limit, $offset);



    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {

        foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
            $preacher[$row->preacher_id]['preacher_id'] = $row->preacher_id;
            $preacher[$row->preacher_id]['preacher_name'] = $row->first_name . ' ' . $row->last_name;
            $preacher[$row->preacher_id]['preacher_image'] = $row->preacher_image;
            $preacher[$row->preacher_id]['preacher_bio_brief'] = $row->preacher_bio_brief;

            $this->db->select('*');
            $this->db->from('sermons');
            $this->db->where('preacher_id', $row->preacher_id);
            $this->db->order_by('sort_order');
            $sermon_array = array();

            $query = $this->db->get();
            if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
                foreach ($query->result() as $row1) {
                    $sermon_array[$row1->sermon_id] ['sermon_image'] = $row1->sermon_image;
                    $sermon_array[$row1->sermon_id] ['sermon_title'] = $row1->sermon_title;
                    $sermon_array[$row1->sermon_id] ['audio_file'] = $row1->audio_file;
                    $sermon_array[$row1->sermon_id] ['sermon_description'] = $row1->sermon_description;
                }
            }
            $preacher[$row->preacher_id]['sermon'] = $sermon_array;
        }
        return $preacher;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll add comments where I fix the code.

```
function viewAllpreachers($offset=0, $limit=null) 
{
    $preacher_ids = array();
    $this->db->distinct('preacher_id');
    $this->db->select('preacher_id');
    $this->db->from('sermons');

    $query = $this->db->get();
    $preachers = array();
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) 
    {

        foreach ($query->result() as $key => $res1) 
        {
            $preacher = array();
            $this->db->select('*');
            $this->db->from('preacher');
            $this->db->where('preacher_id', $res1->preacher_id);
            $this->db->order_by('first_name');
            $query = $this->db->get('', $limit, $offset);
            if ($query->num_rows() > 0) 
            {
                foreach ($query->result() as $row) 
                {
                    $preacher[$row->preacher_id]['preacher_id'] = $row->preacher_id;
                    $preacher[$row->preacher_id]['preacher_name'] = $row->first_name . ' ' . $row->last_name;
                    $preacher[$row->preacher_id]['preacher_image'] = $row->preacher_image;
                    $preacher[$row->preacher_id]['preacher_bio_brief'] = $row->preacher_bio_brief;

                    $this->db->select('*');
                    $this->db->from('sermons');
                    $this->db->where('preacher_id', $row->preacher_id);
                    $this->db->order_by('sort_order ');
                    $sermon_array = array();

                    $query = $this->db->get();
                    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) 
                    {
                        foreach ($query->result() as $row1) 
                        {
                            $sermon_array[$row1->sermon_id] ['sermon_image'] = $row1->sermon_image;
                            $sermon_array[$row1->sermon_id] ['sermon_title'] = $row1->sermon_title;
                            $sermon_array[$row1->sermon_id] ['audio_file'] = $row1->audio_file;
                            $sermon_array[$row1->sermon_id] ['sermon_description'] = $row1->sermon_description;
                        }
                        $preacher[$row->preacher_id]['sermon'] = $sermon_array;
                        $preachers[] = $preacher;
                        // I moved this code, so it will only add preachers who have sermons.
                    }

                }
                //return $preacher;
                // If you return here, it'll always return the first preacher.
            }
        }
        return $preachers;
        // Here we return all preachers, that are added  
    }
    return false;
}
```